# Coq: Error: Unable to locate library Coq.extraction.Extraction

Tags: coq

I'm taking the "Software foundations" course. Can't run the "Extraction" chapter.
It fail on the first line `Require Coq.extraction.Extraction.` with the message `Coq: Error: Unable to locate library Coq.extraction.Extraction.`

I'm running it in CoqIde.

coqc -v:
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.6 (October 2017)
compiled on Oct 28 2017 14:23:55 with OCaml 4.05.0

CoqIde version: 8.6

CoqTop arguments: -Q /home/evgenii/mysources/coq/coq-excercises/lf LF

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing that line with `Require Extraction.` (`Coq.extraction.Extraction` seems to be a backwards-incompatible form.)

8.6 is pretty old, so you might have other compatibility problems if that doesn't match the version used by your distribution of Software Foundations. Have a look in `Preface.v` for the expected Coq version, and consider upgrading if there is a mismatch.

Comment: Thank you, seems that I got this version from apt-get in Ubuntu. Will have to build a new one myself.

Comment: @simpadjo `opam` is the standard way to install `coq`and it should be easier than building it manually.

Comment: @eponier thank you, it works now. I was misguided by instructions from github

Comment: @simpadjo What instructions? If the formulation can be improved, do not hesitate to notify the right people (e.g. by opening an issue).